# PIE.htc not working for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I downloaded uncompressed version of PIE.htc on my server.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">          
            <div class="inside-wrapper">
                testing
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.css**

```
    .inside-wrapper{  
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
        width: 150px;
        height:150px;   
        behavior: url(PIE.htc);
        position:relative;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

I also added a **PIE.htaccess** with the following code

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

*My IIS server is already configured to .hta as text/x-component*

**All the files are located here**

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testing
```

I don't get rounded corners in IE8. What am I missing?

**If I hit F12 -> see the css -> uncheck `behavior:url(PIE.htc); border-radius:5px` -> and then check it again, it works BUT when I refresh the page the rounded corners are lost.**

Comment: if you're using IIS, the htaccess file isn't going to do anything.

Comment: It's working now. I downloaded the compressed file. Weird enough - the uncompressed file (PIE_uncompressed.htc) does not work.

Comment: glad you solved it. Put the solution down as an answer below and accept it. this will help others who may find the question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by downloading the compressed file (PIE.htc). The uncompressed file (PIE_uncompressed.htc) does not work.